# How to delete multiple calendar events at once

Tags: calendars, outlook

A few months ago, I imported all of my classes to the WP calendar, now my classes are over, but there are still events on the calendar. How can I delete them all at once? In web interface you can only delete one by one - which is kind of annoying.

Is there a way to clear all events in calendar?
Is there a way to reset whole calendar?

Comment: You can probably mass delete event using Outlook on your PC

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can delete events *en masse* on your phone. The only way to wipe a calendar of all events is to delete and recreate it.

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Log in to https://calendar.live.com
2. Click on the gear icon in the top right corner and select Options
3. Click on the calendar you want to wipe
4. In the top bar, click Delete, then confirm you want to delete the calendar
5. Repeat step 2
6. Underneath the list of calendars, click on "Add a new calendar" to recreate the calendar you just deleted